# How can I replace the bleed plug for my towel rail?

Tags: plumbing, screws, radiator

I have a very similar type of radiator as this:

[image]

However doing a bathroom refit, I have somehow lost the radiator bleed plug which is shown in the picture above. So if I turn the radiator on, it obviously starts to leak water. Any idea what that is called/where I could get a replacement?

Comment: I was reluctant to answer earlier because I wasn't sure of myself, but any info is better than none. I call them bleed screws. They come in different sizes and configurations depending on their exact function. You should perhaps inquire with the supplier of the fixture for a replacement, especially if a matching finish is important.

Comment: Is there only one bleed plug?  I forget the website I used (5+ years ago) but I sent then like 5-6 screws/nuts I needed and they sent back replacements.  They even called me and said one wasn't a perfect match so do I want to get extra to replace all.  Was like $2 per.  Sorry not at home so can't look in my Outlook for the site.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest thing to determine will be the screw diameter and pitch.  A visit to a plumbing supply will likely yield some typical samples to try.  Just don't force them in, it should start smoothly and tighten to a firm stop.

[This link lists](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Radiator-bleeding-key-brass-bleed-valves-3mm-6mm-13mm-/260710744789) what must be common UK bleed valve sizes 3mm, 6mm, and 13mm, the ad lists all three and a key with delivery (to UK) for under £2.

[image]

How close is [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Heated-Traditional-Chrome-Towel-Rail-Radiator-Rad-RT08-/330593982434?pt=UK_Bathroom_Mats_Rugs&hash=item4cf8efd7e2) to your unit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call up or visit some local plumbing shops and see if they have any bleed screws for you.

Seems like a really obscure item that is hard to find online.

It would help if you knew the manufacturer, and especially help if you knew the model.